# add product to cart with product options

Tags: php, web-services, api, magento, attributes

i try to add product to cart wih this code :

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 
        try{
        $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionID, $cartID, array(array(
        'product_id' => $productID,
        'sku' => $sku,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'options' => null,
        'bundle_option' => null,
        'bundle_option_qty' => null,
        'links' => null
        )));  

        } catch(SoapFault $e){

           $result = $e->getMessage();
           }
```

i found it from this link : [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html)

on link example it`s pass null for options if i want to add options like color or size or ... to product and then add the prodoct to cart what should i do ?

Comment: is it  bundle product??

Comment: @AmitBera  yes it is bundle product.

Comment: @AmitBera i want to try it with simple product too .